# Django - Display a list of calculated fields in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am passing a list of querysets and a list of total prices to my template. I am using the reverse relationship of my Requisition Table to display each line that exists for that requisition. I am passing the total price of the requisition(adding all the lines prices together). I am trying to display in a table format each record with the cumulative price at the bottem next to a submit button. My initial thought was to obviously iterate over the list but that is causing me a problem because I would be nesting three for loops so it is not displaying the result like intended.

### pending_action.html

```
    <h1>Pending Action</h1> 
            {% for req_header in req_header_list %}         
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#req{{ req_header.id }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">                       
                                {{ req_header }} 
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                        </div>

                        <div id="req{{ req_header.id }}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Line</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Total Price</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>    
                                {% for line in req_header.par_req_line.all %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{line}}</td>
                                        <td>{{line.description}}</td>
                                        <td>{{line.quantity}}</td>
                                        <td>{{line.total_price}}<td>
                                        <td>{{line.status}}</td>                     
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="#" method="POST">       
                                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                         <!--WANT TO DISPLAY THE TOTAL PRICE PER REQUISITION HERE                                         
                                          {{price_list.0}}
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>   
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

### views.py

```
def pending_action(request):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
    user_req_headers = Requisition.objects.filter(username=user)
    complete_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.get(status='Completed')
    req_header_list = []
    total_price = 0
    price_list = []

    for req_header in user_req_headers:
        req_lines = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req = req_header) & ~Q(status=complete_status))
        for line in req_lines:
            if line.parent_req not in req_header_list:
                req_header_list.append(line.parent_req)

            total_price = total_price + line.total_price
        price_list.append(total_price)
        total_price = 0

    return render(request, 'req/pending_action.html', {'req_header_list':req_header_list, 'price_list':price_list})
```

### models.py

```
class Requisition(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='req_user')
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)



class RequisitionLine(models.Model):

    parent_req = models.ForeignKey('Requisition', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='par_req_line' )
    sequence = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item_code = models.ForeignKey(
        'items.ItemMaster', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='req_item', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    extra_information = models.TextField(blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0,null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00,null=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00,null=True)
    purchase_order = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True,null=True)
    po_line = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    req_delivery_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    act_delivar_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey('RequisitionStatus', related_name='req_status', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    assistance = models.ForeignKey('users.UserRoles', related_name='req_assist', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to= ~Q(role='Requestor'))
    catagory = models.ForeignKey('items.ItemCatagory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='line_cat',  blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('parent_req','sequence')
```

### StackTrace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/req/pending/

Django Version: 2.1
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'req',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'items']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\###\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\###\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\###\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\###\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\###\Documents\Python\django\lambda\req\views.py" in pending_action
  273.     user_reqs = Requisition.objects.filter(par_req_line__in=user_req_lines_incomplete).annotate(aggregated_price=sum('par_req_line__total_price'))

Exception Type: TypeError at /req/pending/
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: That is a highly inefficient query. Don't do queries inside loops.. or you're going to have a bad time (south park guy voice)

Comment: Loop over something like this: `RequisitionLine.objects.filter(parent_req__username=user, status__status__neq='Completed')`  -- remove all your other queries, you shouldnt need them. This goes OUTSIDE the loop/ this would be what you loop over.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Thank you for the advice but I dont see any other way of doing it. I added the relevant models. A user may have multiple Requisitions which may have multiple lines per Requisition. I want to get all the headers that have lines with the 2 filters i applied which is why i was adding them to a list. What approach would you take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your views.py to return a single queryset of Requisition objects that match your conditions, annotated with the aggregated price data you want to provide. Then you need to refactor your html template to iterate over the single queryset. Using the Django ORM to its max will make your code much shorter, and will run much faster.

## In views.py

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def pending_action(request):
    user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(parent_req__username=request.user).exclude(status__status='Completed'))
    user_reqs = Requisition.objects.filter(par_req_line__in=user_requisition_lines_incomplete).annotate(aggregated_price=Sum('par_req_line__total_price'))
    return render(request, 'req/pending_action.html', {'user_reqs':user_reqs})
```

Please note that there's a little trickery going on under the hood in the Django ORM when you do a filter on a related model before annotating on that model. When you `filter(par_req_line__in` that also means that the annotation that happens later in the line will only be calculated on `par_req_line`s that match the filter condition. So your aggregation will sum only the lines that are in `user_req_lines_incomplete`. I'm 95% sure that's what you want, but feel free to clarify if you're looking for a different condition. I struggled a bit to follow all of your code with the many for loops and names. (No judgement.)

## In pending_action.html

```
<!-- I took out most of your HTML to simplify -->
<h1>Pending Action</h1> 

{% for req in user_reqs %}
    <h5>{{req}}</h5> <!-- You can show whatever you want for your req here -->
    {% for line in req.par_req_line.all %x} 
        <tr>
            <td>{{line}}</td>
            <td>{{line.description}}</td>
            <td>{{line.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{line.total_price}}<td>
            <td>{{line.status}}</td>                     
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    Total price: {{req.aggregated_price}} <!-- Use the annotated data here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed! Also, thank you for teaching me new concepts, I had no idea about that you could do aggregation in django as I am still fairly new to using it. I am getting a type error when i try to get the aggregated price. Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. I cant figure out why.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the error? Is it happening in the view or in the template?

Comment: I posted it above. It is happening in the view.

Comment: Possibly due to a typo. sum should be Sum. Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I didnt realize django had its own Sum function compared to the python standard sum function. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Now that you're getting into the more powerful Django ORM features, it's time for you to read the docs on `.distinct()` and plan to do a lot of edge case testing. Thar be dragons

Comment: Really glad you gave this answer. It allowed me to go back and rewrite my other view functions that were just as bad if not worse. Thanks again!